# How to setup the phpmyadmin configuration storage within cpanel

Tags: phpmyadmin, cpanel

I have a website running cPanel.  The host used to allow for remote access to my mySQL database but they turned that off so I'm stuck with phpmyadmin since it's hosted locally.  My primary reason for needing remote access was so I could store my queries and not have to redo them every time or copy and paste from a different document.

I did some poking around and found the phpmyadmin can store/bookmark queries if I setup the configuration storage.  However, I'm not a DBA and really don't understand what I need to do.  The page talks about running some scripts to create a bunch of tables or something but I don't seem to have those scripts.

My host said we are running the version of phpmyadmin that is bundled with cpanel and if I make any changes they will just get overwritten by the next update and I might have to manually install the full version of phpmyadmin.

Can anyone shed any light on this for me and give me some guidance?  I just need to be able to type up some queries and save them into phpmyadmin so when I go back in I can just pick them off the list and run them.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

So first thing, it's very possible to [install your own phpMyAdmin](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html)  to your web root folder and work independently of what your host has provided.

Setting up the configuration storage is [pretty straightforward](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage); basically you edit then import the `create_tables.sql` file, which you can do from within phpMyAdmin; you also have to create the user for this account and set that user's name and password in to `config.inc.php`. The script is included with the standard phpMyAdmin installation; it's unlikely that your host has made it available to you with the installation they've provided for you, but you'll get it as part of the standard phpMyAdmin download.

Then you can use the bookmark feature which sounds like it will fulfill your needs very nicely.